# Why google cardboard uses double-convex aspherical lenses?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Google cardboard VR version 2 uses double-convex aspherical lenses with different radius of curvature.
The full specifications are in the [official google cardboard site](https://vr.google.com/cardboard/) 
in the manufacturers section, the file lens.pdf inside of wwgc_manufacturers_kit.zip

What is the reason for the use of that specific lens? 
and 
Why the surface with the biggest radius of curvature is close to the cellphone screen?

Comment: I removed the download link and replaced it with a link to the site.  It's not so polite to have people download something unexpectedly.